# Send static data from one php to another

Tags: php, html

I have a php file `results.php` with a grid of different items (each item is a row from the result of a certain query). When I click an item it takes me to another php file `details.php` where I want to show more details in the new page about the specific item I clicked.

```php
function showAsItem($row) {
    $defaultValue = $row[1];
    $itemClassname="item";
    $titleClassname="title";
    $imageClassname="image";
    $infoClassname="infolist";
    $link="details.php";
    $target="_top";
    $img="https://barcelonando.com/es/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/barceloneta.jpg";
    $alt="Imagen de $row";
    
    echo '<div class="'.$itemClassname.'">';
        echo '<div class="'  .$titleClassname.  '">';
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'" target="' .$target. '">' .ucfirst($row[0]). '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="'  .$imageClassname.  '">';
            echo '<a href="' .$link. '" target="' .$target. '">';
            echo '<img src="'  .$img. '" alt="'  .$alt.  '"/>';
            echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="'  .$infoClassname.  '">';
            echo '<ul>';
            echo '<li> Poblaci&oacute;n: '  .$row[1]. '</li>';
            echo '<li> Esperanza de vida: '  .$defaultValue. '</li>';
            echo '<li> Inmigrantes: '  .$defaultValue. '</li>';
            echo '<li> Transportes: '  .$defaultValue. '</li>';
            echo '<li> Accidentes: '  .$defaultValue. '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I only know how to send info from one webpage to another when it is an input type, but in this case I want to send the item static info (I just need to send the name of the item I clicked). Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: It depends on `href` attribute. We don't know how `$link` looks, it can be eg. like `detail.php?id=123`..

Comment: What do you mean: "it takes me to another file"? Is the page reloading? You could just put the name at the end of URL adding: ?name=$name and then, in the new file, read $_GET['name']

Comment: By another file I mean going to the specific new page built by 'details.php' . All the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pavel pointed out, using a URL parameter should work for you. Every item must have a unique number or name associated with them.

Do not use their array index or similar, because that will change in the future.

Your example code has `$row` use numeric indexes - whichever one of them is unique you can use as a URL parameter. If you don't have one, you have to create one. Preferably one that will not change when the data is updated. That is where databases will use numeric IDs, but you can use a string as well, as long as you can identify the item from the `details.php`.

Example link: `$link="details.php?id=" . $row[2];`. Replace 2 with whatever is a unique number / name for every row.

Instead of only supplying the `$row` in your function, you can supply the row's ID as a separate parameter if that is what you need. Depends on how you organized this outside of your example code.

In this case you change the function as well:

```php
function showAsItem($row, $rowId) {
  // ...
  $link="details.php?id=" . $rowId;
  // ...
}
```

In `details.php` you can access this variable with `$_GET`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
```